# How to Indent Highlighted (with Margins Adjusted) Paragraphs with Mdframed

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, indentation, paragraphs, mdframed

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \parindent 10pt
 
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=red!20,innerleftmargin=1.5pt,innerrightmargin=1.5pt,leftmargin=-1.5pt,rightmargin=-1.5pt]
\lipsum[13]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

Though I have specified `\parindent 10pt`, the colorized (margin adjusted) paragraph is not indented. I suppose that this should not come as a surprise; however, I have not been able to figure out an efficient way to have such paragraphs indented. Placing `\hskip 10pt` immediately prior to `\lipsum[13]` works---but I don't want to have to do this multiple times throughout an actual document.

QUESTION: How may I specify in the code that a paragraph which immediately follows `\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=red!20,innerleftmargin=1.5pt,innerrightmargin=1.5pt,leftmargin=-1.5pt,rightmargin=-1.5pt]` should be indented, say 10pt?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept to change to `tcolorbox`, this could be a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent 10pt
 
 \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
enhanced, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt, boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=1.5pt, bottom=1.5pt, before upper=\hspace{10pt}, colback=red!20, #1
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=red!20,innerleftmargin=1.5pt,innerrightmargin=1.5pt,leftmargin=-1.5pt,rightmargin=-1.5pt]
\lipsum[13]
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[13]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}[colback=green!20, boxsep=2mm]
\lipsum[13]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer.